# why does npm and node have two different versions

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

So i'm checking the versions on both npm and node, which I believe have the same action from their commands, but they show different versions
Here's the code --

```
$ node -v
v6.10.3
$ npm -v
5.3.0
$ brew upgrade node
Error: node 8.4.0 already installed
$ brew upgrade npm
enter code here
```

Comment: Npm and Node are two different applications. Thats why the have dofferent version numbers? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 0):

> This error appears to be caused by the module v8-debug possibly not
>   being compatible with that version of node. grunt-cli doesn't use
>   native addons so check your package.json install script or try
>   installing grunt-cli from another folder.
>
> Also it should be npm install grunt-cli -g to install globally as
>   grunt-cli just gives access to the command grunt to run local grunt
>   projects.