# Different versions of node on the same computer

Tags: node.js

I am working on two different angular projects on my computer.

If I run `node -v` on **project A's** root folder I get `version 10.15.3` and if I run `node -v` on **project B's** root folder I get another `version 12.1`.

I don't understand why node is showing two different versions.

If I check the `PATH` of the node command it points to the same file `/usr/bin/node`.

Comment: maybe your projects use nvm (node version manager) https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: @Salines you clearly didn't read the question

Answer (score 0):

thanks for replaying back. I am not using nvm.  However I was checking another question here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45993776/why-does-npm-and-node-have-two-different-versions)

```
node -v v10.15.3
nodejs -v v12.1.0
```

node comes from **apt-get installed package (on Debian)**.
I was having issues when serving an ionic app, so I decided to **remove npm version of node (v12.1.0)**:

```
npm remove -g node
```

Then I open another terminal and now node and nodejs are showing **same version 10.15.3**. For my testing purposes I need LTS version instead of latest in order to ensure less bug-prone code.